# Can I verify if message is sent successfully using Response<SendReceipt> in Azure Storage Queue

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-storage-queues

I am using the Azure Storage Queue Client to send base 64 encoded string messages. A very straight forward usage. I have the following code snippet:

```
            var options = new QueueClientOptions
            {
                MessageEncoding = QueueMessageEncoding.Base64
            };

            var _queueClient = new QueueClient(settings.Value.ConnectionString, settings.Value.Name, options);
            var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messageObject, jsonSetting);

         _queueClient.SendMessageAsync(message);
```

I know that `SendMessageAsync( . . .)` returns `Response<SendReceipt>` how do I use that to verify if a message is sent successfully or not ?
`SendReceipt` has `MessageId` and `InsetionTime` properties but the documentation does not specify what happens to these properties if message does not get sent. Does the queue simply returns null receipt or an object with default values ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to send a message to a queue using `SendMessageAsync` and if for some reason message is not sent, an exception is raised. You will not receive anything in the `Response<SendReceipt>`.

You will need to wrap your `await _queueClient.SendMessageAsync(message);` in a try/catch block. If no exception is raised that would mean the message is sent successfully.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response that makes it easier to handle , Can I ask where you saw that information,  because I couldnt see  that from the documentation

Comment: I just ran the code :)

Comment: nothing beats than running the code and seeing it yourself , I am going to try that , Thanks Gaurav!